# Xunit test on if conditions in a button click event

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have been searching for awhile, but haven't found a suitable answer.
I have a button click event that compares two DateTimesusing `if` statements.

```
public void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Parameters for SQL command
if (AnticipatedDatePicker.Value < OutDatePicker.Value)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error. The Anticipated Check In date must be after the Check Out date");
                    }
                if (OutDatePicker.Value < DateTime.Today)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error. The Check Out Date must not be before today.");
                }
//else statement here
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a unit test (I'm using xunit) that checks whether or not those if statements are valid. I was trying to use `[Theory]` and adding in DateTime as `Inline` data. However, I am not sure xunit supports datetime as `inline`data. Even if it did I'm not sure how I would test this.

I did come up with:

```
 [Theory]
        [InlineData("2020-12-30", "2020-12-31")]

        public void checkDates(DateTime first, DateTime second)
        {
            
            Assert.True(first < second);
            Assert.False(first == second);
            Assert.False(first < DateTime.Today);

        }
```

And it does pass. However, it doesn't really touch the SaveButton_click event, nor the values it uses.
If there a way for me to pass `first` and `second` values to `AnticipatedDatePicker.Value` and `OutDatePicker.Value` and test the actual button _click event and whether or not the `if` statements are tiggered?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to use MVVM pattern here, so you should use bindings, commands and get rid of that button click handler.

Another problem is `DateTime.Today` - you need to find the way to mock that... May you can create some service to wrap that. Otherwise I see no way to create proper tests.